# reverse order of Array in Ruby with index counter

Tags: ruby

I have an array `@dates`, that are UTC dates, and in increasing order.  I want to flip the indices of the array so that the dates are in descending order.   I am familiar with JS an Java, and don't know how to either use a pointer/index counter in ruby.

```
@dates = [//dates are in here already]

@reverseDates = []
@dates.each do |d|
  @reverseDates << @dates.last
end

@dates = @reverseDates
```

Part of the issue as well is that I think it is duplicating the last index of `@dates`, not moving it to the other array when it pushes.

So I got it it working by prepending the array, but how do you include index counters in Ruby to accomplish this?

```
@reverseDates = []
@dates.each do |d|
  @reverseDates.unshift(d)
end

@dates = @reverseDates
```

Comment: In the first example `@dates.last` never changes in the `each` because `@dates` never changes in the `each`. See [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) for how to iterate *with* an index; however, this is not the real problem, nor the real solution.

Comment: I recommend reading the full API of the `Enumerable` module from A to Z, each one of these methods is so powerful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby has reversing an array built in:

```
@dates.reverse!
```

From http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-reverse-21

Comment: I would recommend using `reverse` as I find that reducing side-effects creates easier-to-follow code and reduces surprises.